# Undo function isn't working properly after it reaches the game initial state

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, stack, undo

I am trying to build an undo function for my board  that return to the previous
board state.
I have also build a temp Save function that creates a list with all the previous game states. But when i undo till the board reaches to the initial game state(all blank) and then play a move ,lets say A3 in a 4x4 board, the undo function cannot turn back to the initial state (all blank) and it saves the current move as the very first state of the board so the initial blank state is vanished...

If anyone has an idea of what i may be doing wrong please comment.
Any help is appreciated.

I am a begginer programmer but I hope my explanation of the problem is quite informative.Following I will place the tempSave function the Undo Function and the struct that I refer as Board State:

Here is the struct for the board states:

```
typedef struct state *stateptr;
struct state {
char **table;
stateptr prev;
};

extern stateptr last=NULL;
```

Following the tmpSave function:

```
void tmpSave(char **table,int dim)
{
//dim is the dimension of the dim x dim board and i have a main 
//function that calls tmpSave after each move with the above parameters
int i,j;
stateptr newstate;
newstate=malloc(sizeof(struct state));

newstate->table=malloc(dim*sizeof(char*));
for(i=0; i<dim; i++)
{
    newstate->table[i]=malloc(dim*sizeof(char));
}

for(i=0; i<dim; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<dim; j++)
    {
        newstate->table[i][j]=table[i][j];
    }
}
    if(last!=NULL)
    {
        newstate->prev=last;
        last=newstate;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nHi!!\n");
        last=newstate;
        last->prev=NULL;
    }
}
```

And finally the undo function that return a table that will be printed properly in the main function , START flag determines if we are at the initial(blank)state:

```
char **undo(short int *START)
{
stateptr prev=last->prev;
if(last->prev==NULL)
{
    printf("\nCan't further undo\n");
}
else
{
    free(last);
    last=prev;

}
if(last->prev==NULL) *START=1;

return last->table;
}
```

example:
1.firstly the board is blank
2.Move:
 
 `0 0 0 0
 w 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0`

3.Another move:
 
 `0 0 w 0
 w 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0`

4.undo till the initial(blank state)

 `0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0`
 At this point the 'last' pointer is equal to the initial state so the last->prev=NULL and the *START turn to one,this one is used to define the move that is done by a bot player (don't take it under serious consideration)

5.Another move:

`0 0 0 w 
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0`

6.Undo state (Here the described problem appears):

 `0 0 0 w
 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0`

while it should be:

 `0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0`
(intial-blank state)..

and after that the initial state is the one the false one with the 'w' on (1,4).

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: When is `*START` ever reset to zero? Provide a [mcve] so we can see the answer to this and other questions.

Comment: xing is right about the memory leak, i fixed that but I don't think it has to do with the problem described.

Comment: I added some printf's that actually show me that after the 5th step in the example above, the tmpSave function saves ,as the initial state, the last one with the 'w' printed...but i don't understand how ...in the undo function i noted taht if last->prev is NULL then i wont do any changes and return the blank board itself...so it seems logical to me that  the tmpSave would save the move after its done and make it 'last' one so the last->prev points to the blank board.....after all i call tmpSave after each move is done.

Comment: xing I've done that ...it didn't make any difference I really don't see why my code has such a bug...but I'll found out soon and I will edit this post then..Thanks for the help mates !